# How to force execution of a function and then return a simple something else in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

So I'm making my own primitive shell language parser and I thought I would make my commands (such as cd) expressions so that I can leave some space for them to return values.

Now I have made some kind of parser and I have a naked expression in my statement consumer.

I hope for your sake that I do not have to provide you with the whole code. This is the problematic part:

```
-- it has other patterns...
makeStatement :: Statement -> VarTable -> Maybe VarTable
makeStatement (Exp exp) vt = ??? 
makeStatement (If ..........
...

data Expression = Val   Int
                | Booly  Bool
                | Var   String
                | Cmd String [String]
                  deriving (Show)

data Statement = Assignment String Expression
               | If Expression Statement
               | IfElse Expression Statement Statement
               | Exp Expression
                deriving (Show)
eval :: VarTable -> Expression -> Maybe Int
```

So I want to force execution of exp in case its a `Cmd` but return the same vt it began with.

Comment: What would you gain in this function by knowing if `Exp` is a `Cmd`?  You don't seem to want to make any decision off of this.  Would it be more like `makeStatement (Expr (Cmd _ _)) vt = Nothing; makeStatement _ vt = Just vt`?

Comment: I need to run the command in case it has something to do with the IO

Comment: So do you need your `makeStatement` to return an `IO` action instead?  You won't be able to "run" a command presumably without performing an IO action.

Comment: No. I want `makeStatement` to return vt after evaluating exp

Comment: I suppose I want something with deepseq but I do not know how to use it

Comment: What do you want to happen from forcing the evaluation of a `Cmd` value?

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic Do you think that forcing evaluation of an IO action causes it to be executed? It doesn't - that's the whole point of IO.

Comment: Forcing the evaluation of an expression can only affect the memory footage and run time (possibly including non termination) of your program. It can not "do" anything else. Why do you want to force evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you're probably going to need some composite type to represent the three possible types your expressions can return.
Something like

```
data Value = Number Int | Boolean Bool | String String | Unit
```

The `Unit` one is for expressions that don't return anything.
Now, since *some* of your expressions might have side-effects, you're definitely going to have to wrap *everything* up into IO. It doesn't matter that there are pure expressions because the compiler doesn't know which one is which.

```
eval :: VarTable -> Expression -> IO Value
```

Now your `makeStatement` (something like `runStatement` might be a better name) would look like this

```
makeStatement :: Statement -> VarTable -> IO VarTable
makeStatement (Exp exp)    vt = eval exp >> return vt
makeStatement (If cond th) vt = do
    c <- eval cond
    case c of
        Boolean True -> makeStatement th vt
        _            -> return vt --maybe handle the case where c isn't even Boolean
...
```

With this setup you can see that we can do what I'm guessing you wanted. `eval`uate the expression, and then discard it's result and just return the `VarTable` unchanged.